# Set PHP include_path for site folders rather than entire web server

Tags: php, apache

If this should be posted elsewhere please advise. I have reviewed other questions and answers but not been able to resolve my query so far.

I have wampserver running:
Server Software: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 - Port defined for Apache: 80
My notebook o/s is Win10.

I am very new to this and just working through a PHP and MySQL book. I am putting multiple example sections in a local website for training so I don't have one area for includes but several with the root of the site structure:
eg: myweb/book01/includes; myweb/book02/includes

echo get_include_path(); shows .;C:\php\pear and I don't want to change the php.ini file as it may work for one myweb/book01 but not myweb/book02

I can set include paths manually for each page using ../ format but as the directory structure changes these fail unless manually edited which doesn't seem the right thing to do.

Is there a way to set an include_path that can be defined and used by specific pages and/or sections rather than a whole web root?

I can then just set once for each section (book01, book02) in the section's header file.

I have tried the following but keep getting 'Warning // failed to open stream' and ' Failed opening ... for inclusion' error messages:

set_include_path(get_include_path().":"."D\data\url\d4th\training\includes");

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/training/includes/test_header.inc.php';

set_include_path ('.:/d4th/training/includes');

set_include_path('D:\data\url\d4th\training\includes');

set_include_path('.;D:\data\url\d4th\training\includes');

include ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/training/includes/header.inc.php');  // value for the above is 'd4th'

I'm sure there's a relatively straight forward solution. Been doing this for hours now and can't get my head round it.

Comment: __DIR__ and __FILE__ also give the same errors. I've used includes before on websites without issue. It's the running and testing locally that is causing me issues

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the include path.

```
__DIR__
```

will always give you a prefix of your current directory.

```
<?php

include __DIR__.'/includes/test_header.inc.php';
```

There are much better ways to structure your applications.  If you're just learning PHP, here's a great resource:

https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners